# Extract data from mysql database, pass to script to create new user

Tags: php, mysql, database, linux

I'm looking to have a user enter their details on a registration form which sends the data they enter to a mysql database. Things like firstName, lastName, and password. I have that working.

What I then need to do is have a script run every few minutes that extracts that data from the database and adds a new user to the linux system (and create directories with the user entered firstName) which is what i'm having problems with doing.

so far, i've got:

```
$MYSQL -e "select username from registeredUsers" | sudo xargs -L 1 useradd
```

But I need to extract the password from the database, and make a www directory from the name entered as well.

Comment: Why doesn't the PHP script which posts the user data into the database simply invoke `useradd` itself?

Comment: because it requires sudo

Comment: So?  PHP can invoke `sudo`.

Comment: How about storing the username in a variable in your script and then setting the password like this `echo YourPass | passwd $YourUser --stdin`

Comment: Please could you tell me how to do it via the php?

Comment: You can add your the user that runs your php scripts to the list of sudoers, you can edit your sudoers file and add `nobody ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script` this will allow the user 'nobody' to execute script with super user privileges without a password, then if you call sudo from within PHP to that exact script it won't require a password

Comment: thats insecure though?

Comment: I share your opinion, this isn't the way I would do it, but this will only work for that particular script though, I mean the user 'nobody' will only be able to run this script with escalated privileges, so maybe this works for you!